# How do I construct an efficient algorithm for finding vertex which is furthest from the set S of vertices?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, dijkstra, greedy, divide-and-conquer

Given a undirected weighted graph with n vertices and m edges. How do I construct an algorithm which takes at most **O((n+m) log(n+m))** for finding the vertex which it's min shortest path distance to a set of vertices S \in V is maximized?

I know I can loop through all vertices and using dijkstra's algorithm find the shortest path to each of the vertices in S but that will surely take much more than O((n+m) log(n+m)).

Comment: Use reverse of Dijkstra's Algorithm to find length shortest paths from all nodes to your target set at once.

Comment: @stark Im sorry but I don't understand. Isn't it the case that it would take O(n^2*m) if we try to find all the shortest paths in the graph?

Comment: DA finds the shortest path from a node to every node in the graph in O(E logV) time for E edges, V vertices.  Reverse DA finds shortest path to a node from every node in the graph in the same O.  Having multiple target nodes just affects initialization, not complexity.

Comment: Sorry If I sound like a complete newbie cause I am.. :) But as our set S can be quite big, (something like n/4). how can that not affect the complexity if we need to loop over all vertices in S and run reverse DA on them? Thanks for your help and patience with me.

Comment: Typical DA is set an array to all -1 except one node set to 0 (distance to/from target node).  You just set S nodes to 0 and initialize your starting list of nodes to examine to all neighbors of those S nodes.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming from your ideas (possible use of dijkstra's shortest path algorithm) that weight of every edge is greater or equal than zero.

A clean solution to your problem is to create a new vertex *v* and add zero weight edges between *v* and every vertex in S. Run dijkstra's algorithm from *v* and the answer you look for is the farthest vertex from *v*.

You can prove by yourself that solution of your problem is equal to the one calculated on the new graph as it is straighforward. Also, it only run dijkstra's algorithm once so it fits on your time complexity constraints.